# Feynman Graphs for scalar fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

What would be the Feynman Graphs be like for scalar fields like  $\phi$ $\phi$ interactions? Also, how can it be summed up to orders of Mass^6.

I know it is the 2 pt function of the scalar fields. I don't understand how can I use only this interaction to draw and evaluate the feynmann graphs.

Can someone clearly explain this concept?

Comment: Do you know what Feynman diagrams are? For free theories, they are not required, since the 2-point function can be evaluated exactly.

Comment: What if I have to draw the degenerate looking feynman diagrams for the 2 point function of the $\phi$ fields but with the mass term $\dfrac{1}{2} m^{2} \phi^{2}$ in the Lagrangian acting as an interaction term instead of simply a kinetic term?

Comment: Then you should’ve emphasized that in your question. The only allowed connected diagrams in this case are the “bamboo” graphs which sum giving the geometric series.

Comment: Do you mean the "bamboo" graphs will give me the sum up to orders of $m^{6}$?

Comment: No, they will give you an infinite geometric series which is equal to the full massive 2-point function.

Comment: Then what would the feynman rule be for the $\phi\phi$ interaction?

Comment: The vertex should give you just $i m^2$.

Comment: You might also find p.6-8 useful in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02604. These diagrams are derived explicitly there and from first principles directly from the path integral. Also, you see there how generic interaction terms affect the story.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you start with a massive Klein-Gordon QFT:

$$ S[\phi] = \int d^4 x \left( \frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2 \right), $$

and you want to treat the massive term as a perturbation around the massless Klein-Gordon QFT just for the heck of it (even though an exact nonperturbative solution exists in this case).

Deriving Feynman rules shouldn't be a big problem. The easiest way is to use path integrals. The derivation then goes in three steps:

**Step 1:** you write down a generic path integral for some expectation functional $\Omega[\phi]$:
$$ \left< \Omega \right> = \int D\phi e^{i S[\phi]} \Omega[\phi]. $$

Now (even though this integral can be computed rigorously) you wish to split $S[\phi]$ into the free (massless) and interaction parts, ending up with
$$ \left< \Omega \right> = \int D\phi e^{i S_0[\phi]}\left( 1 + i\int d^4 x \left( - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 \right) + \frac{1}{2!}i^2 \left[ \int d^4 x \left( - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 \right)\right]^2 + \dots \right) \Omega[\phi]. $$

You then observe that the evaluation of the expectation $\Omega$ in the full theory is equivalent to the evaluation of the infinite series of the complex expectations containing powers of the space-time integrals in the "free" theory with action $S_0[\phi] = \int d^4 x \frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2$.

You come up with a graphical way to represent the terms in your expansion. Since each of the functionals in the series is evaluated in a free theory, the Wick theorem holds, meaning that it is a sum of contractions. In the contractions, two types of vertices contribute: the external vertices coming from $\Omega$, and internal vertices coming from the integrals containing $m$. Moreover, the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ cancels out $2!=2$ ways to contract a 2-valent vertex, so the expression for the internal (interaction) vertex is:

$$ A(v) = \int d^4 x_v i m^2. $$

Different terms in the series then correspond to diagrams with different number of interaction vertices.

**Step 2:** one remembers that the expectation can be normalized to give $\left<1\right> = 1$, if one does not consider vacuum bubble diagrams. This is standard QFT diagrammatics, textbook authors usually refer to it as "bubble graph exponentiation".

**Step 3:** one writes propagators of the free theory in terms of the momentum integrals:

$$ \Delta(x, y) = \int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i e^{i p x}}{p^2 + i \varepsilon}.$$

Notice the absense of $m$.

Now we can perform the vertex integrals, ending up with the momentum-space Feynman rules:

- For every propagator with momentum $p$ we associate $$\frac{i}{p^2 + i \varepsilon},$$
- For every vertex we associate $$i m^2,$$
- We integrate over undetermined loop momenta, and impose momemtum conservation.

Now one can calculate the actual 2-point function using the rules which she just derived. Consider $\Omega[\phi] = \phi(x) \phi(y)$ for $x, y$ spacetime points. The only contributing diagram is a bamboo graph with $n$ interacting vertices. Its contribution is given by

$$ \left< \phi(x) \phi(y) \right> = \sum_n \int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{i p x} \left( \frac{i}{p^2 + i \varepsilon} \right)^{n+1} \cdot \left( i m^2 \right)^n = \int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{i p x} \frac{i}{p^2 - m^2 + i \varepsilon},$$

where the last equation is the sum of the geometric series. Thus, we obtain the usual massive propagator. Perturbative and nonperturbative methods agree in this case, which is kinda nice.

Comment: Thank you @Solenodon for this response I appreciate it. If I have to do the same thing, but using LSZ formalism and not Path integrals formalism, then how it should be dealt with?